# Uploading video files to IIS 7 through php fails

Tags: php, video, file-upload, iis-7

I'm trying to get my website to upload video's and pictures. As I have made more websites that upload pictures there is no problem on that front, but when i try to upload a video for some reason it can't be found in the `$_FILES` array that contains an uploaded image.

I have already googled and found stuff about the php.ini file and IIS 7 containing max sizes for uploads. these are all set to 1024M:

In php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
```

In IIS 7:

```
maxAllowedContentLength = 1073741824
maxRequestLength = 1073741824
```

After some testing it appears that really small video files do work (192KB) but somewhat bigger doesnt show anyting in the $_FILES array (11MB) but really big files (80MB) gives an error: `The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.`. The problem is that i have set the `maxAllowedContentLength` to 1GB. So that shouldn't happen?! An image of this is down below:

[Image](http://imageshack.us/f/521/35215750.png/)

[image]

Any help or advice is greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given on ServerFault: [ServerFault - Uploading video files to IIS 7 through php fails](https://serverfault.com/questions/341946/uploading-video-files-to-iis-7-through-php-fails). Hope this helps if you have this same problem.